# Browser showing same component for all routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react to recreate a simple route example. Currently only App component is being displayed even if I type anything else after 'localhost:3000/#/' I want to display App component when 'localhost:3000/#/' is called and a Whoops404 component for wildcard. However if I swap the route lines and write Whoops404 component first then every URI shows the Whoops404 component. Whatever route is written first starts showing in browser for every URI. Please let me know what am I missing?
My index.js code is as follows

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import {App} from './components/App'
import {Whoops404} from './components/Whoops404'
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

window.React = React
render(
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path = '/' component = {App}/>
            <Route path = '*' component = {Whoops404}/>
        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>,  
document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

Comment: Did you try to add `exact={true}` to your `App` route ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'exact' keyword in your Route

```
` <Switch>
        <Route exact path = '/' component = {App}/>
        <Route exact path = '*' component = {Whoops404}/>
    </Switch>`
```